# Is it possible to publish an app to the App Store that makes the app universal?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app

Can I transform my iPhone app to be Universal in the next update, and publish the update?

Comment: Yes definitely. You can do that.. From Version 1.0.1 it would become Universal app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is definitely possible to make your app Universal in the next version of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upgrade an app from iPhone/iPad only to Universal.

Going the other way, however, is where you might encounter problems. You cannot downgrade an app from Universal to iPhone/iPad only.